# What should I test in phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I don't know if this is a too localized question, but I don't know what I should be unit testing with PHPUnit. Like for example on a simple user registration/login system, what should I be testing?

I hope you understand what I meant and enlighten me.

Comment: you should google "php unit testing tutorial" and read the PHPUnit manual, it's full of examples.

Comment: You should test everything that's testable. If it's not testable, make it testable.

Comment: please go through some of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+to+unit+test. If there is still questions left then, update your question please to point out what exactly you like to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHPUnit is a *unit testing* suite, hence the name.  Unit testing is, by definition, writing tests for each *unit* -- that is, each class, each method -- as separately as possible from every other part of the system.  Each thing users could use, you want to try to test that it -- and *only* it, apart from everything else -- functions as specified.

Basically, you want to test each public (and possibly protected) method that can possibly fail.  If your inner hacker is wondering "hmm...if i called this function like *this*, would it break?", then write a test that asserts that it doesn't.  Just be careful that you're isolating the component you're testing; otherwise, you just have a bunch of tests that fail but don't give you a clue as to where the real problem is.